# css scale is not applied in react.js(next.js)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, css-selectors

development environment
・next.js
・reacｔ
・typescript

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujlpzTyJp-M
I created a Toolchip using the video above as areference.
but --scale: 1;is not applied.

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

const Index: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="avatar" data-tooltip="aaaa"></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

> style.scss

```
div {
  &.avatar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: blue;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  &.avatar::before,
  &.avatar::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: -0.25rem;
    left: 50%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background: black;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%) scale(var(--scale));
  }
  &.avatar::before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #333;
  }
  &.avatar:hover {
    scale: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: you have a backtick in your css code after the bracket

Comment: I erased it, but it didn't change

Comment: Hi, see @Sergey answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but maybe it should be:

```
  &.avatar:hover {
   transform: scale(1);
  }
```